# How to get Chrome Developer Tools panels to stack vertically

Tags: google-chrome, developer-tools

I have used Chrome Developer tools for quite some time.  I have a wide screen monitor and so I have the tools docked to the right.  I frequently use the network tab to watch calls and see the raw response, and it used to display the content of the response below the list of requests.

This week it suddenly is showing it to the right, making both panels ridiculously narrow and impossible to see anything in either.  I'm trying to figure out if I did something to change it or if a recent update to Chrome might have broken it?  I'm using Chrome version 46.0.2490.80.